# Play wav file in isolated storage with media element

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, mediaelement

I created a small app to record voice and play it, use this code to make a record button and a play button.

I tested the app, recorder worked fine (I used "Windows phone power tools" to get tempAudio.wav from isolated storage of WP emulator and this audio file can played), but the play button didn't play the sound, I can't find anything wrong with the btPlay button :(

XAML code (the two button is roundtoggle button and round button from coding4fun toolkit)

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <toolkit1:RoundToggleButton x:Name="btRecorder" IconUri="..." Checked="btRecorder_Checked" checked="btRecorder_Unchecked"/> 
    <MediaElement x:Name="meVoicePlayer" AutoPlay="False"/>
    <toolkit1:RoundButton x:Name="btPlay" Click="PlayAudio_Click" IconUri="..."/>
</StackPanel>
```

c# code

```
MicrophoneRecorder recorder = new MicrophoneRecorder();

private void btRecorder_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        recorder.Start();                       
    }

private void btRecorder_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        recorder.Stop();
        SaveTempAudio(recorder.Buffer);
    }

public void SaveTempAudio(MemoryStream buffer)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            var bytes = buffer.GetWavAsByteArray(recorder.SampleRate);                
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream audio = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TempAudio.wav",FileMode.Create,isf))
            {
                audio.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }

private void PlayAudio_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {                
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream audio = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TempAudio.wav",FileMode.Open,isf))
            {
                meVoicePlayer.Stop();
                meVoicePlayer.SetSource(audio);
                meVoicePlayer.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0);
                meVoicePlayer.Play();
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning the Emulator. is this the only place, your audio doesn't play? In that case, the answer is simple: The MediaElement does not support playback within the Emulator. See Platform Notes: "Silverlight for Windows Phone" on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: that's freaking weird ! I put a breakpoint on line "meVoicePlayer.Play();" and start, the audio plays ! - remove that breakpoint and start again, the audio doesnt play, again @@ really confused @@

Comment: that's because the stream "audio" gets disposed, after you get out of the using scope{}. remove the using{} and dispose the stream when you press "stopplay"

Comment: I tried to remove "using" and use isf.dispose() manually, but the problem still existed

Answer (score 0):

You must use " Emulator 8.0 Update 3 WVGA 512MB". It work fine